# Why are symmetry transformations connected to the identity necessarily represented by linear unitary operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, group-representations, unitarity

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the following paragraph (taken from *"The Quantum Theory of Fields"*, Weinberg, Vol. 1, Ch.2):

> There is always a trivial symmetry transformation, $\mathscr{R}\rightarrow\mathscr{R}$, represented
>   by the identity operator $U = 1$. This operator is, of course, unitary
>   and linear. Continuity then demands that any symmetry (like a rotation
>   or translation or Lorentz transformation) that can be made trivial by
>   a continuous change of some parameters (like angles or distances or
>   velocities) must be represented by a linear unitary operator $U$ rather
>   than one that is antilinear and antiunitary.

My understanding of this is that, if when specifying a system using parameters $\{x\}$ you find that a symmetry transformation is trivial - i.e. it is explicitly equivalent to the trivial symmetry transformation $U=1$, which is unitary and linear - then if you specify that system using a different set of parameters $\{y\}$ you will find that the symmetry transformation is still linear and unitary. The only restriction is that the new parameters are connected continuously to the old ones, i.e. $y_i=R_i(\{x\})$, where $R$ is a continuous function.

**How exactly do you prove this?** I'd appreciate even a hint at a rough proof.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the point is not continuity of the representation (if continuity is referred to the representation, see the final comment), but a related deeper fact concerning the group itself (though some vague argument based on continuity also of the representation is recurrent in the literature).

One has also to remember that (*Wigner's theorem*) symmetries are represented by unitary/antiunitary operators *up to phases*. This is in agreement with the basic fact of QM in Hilbert spaces that *(pure) states are represented by unit vectors up to arbitrary phases.*

*Groups of symmetries* are therefore represented by maps $G \ni g\mapsto U_g$
where

(a) $U_g$ is defined up to a phase and

(b) the  requirement concerning preservation of the group structure is made weaker ($e$ is the neutral element of $G$):
$$U_e= e^{i\gamma(e)} I\:,\quad U_g U_f =e^{i\gamma(g,f)} U_{g\circ f}$$
for some phases related with the choices of the unitary/antiunitary operators $U_h$.

I stress that, in view of Wigner's theorem, the unitary/antiunitary character of $U_g$ depends on $g$ only (if the Hilbert space has dimension greater than $1$) so, the remaining ambiguity 
in fixing the map $g \mapsto U_g$ concerns only the arbitrary phase and  not the charcter of the operator $U_g$.

A map satisfying (a) and (b) (with a precise choice of the operators $U_g$) is called **unitary projective representation** of $G$.

In some cases, especially when $G$ is equipped with further structures as the *Lie-group* one,  it is possible to redefine the operators $U_g$ by means  suitable phases, $U'_g = \omega_g U_g$, in order to end up with a standard group representation
$$U'_e=  I\:,\quad U'_g U'_f =  U'_{g\circ f}\:.$$ 
This is a difficult co-homological problem with important results, like **Bargmann's  theorem**, I will not address here (Varadarajan's book of the geometry of QM include a list of relevant and very delicate results in this area of the theory of group representation).

Coming back to the main question, consider a group $G$ such that every element $g\in G$ can be decomposed into the product $g= h^2 = h\circ h$. A trivial but physically fundamental example is $\mathbb R$ as additive group.

Next, consider a unitary projective representation $G \ni g \to U_g$ associating every $g$ with a unitary/antiunitary operator $U_g$.

The relation $g=h\circ h$, taking (b) into account, implies $$U_g = e^{i\gamma(h,g)} U_h U_h\:.$$

No matter if $U_h$ is unitary or antiunitary, the composition $U_hU_h$ is unitary and the phases do not play any role. $U_g$ is necessarily unitary here!

In particular, every unitary projective representation of $\mathbb R$  is necessarily made of *unitary* operators (even if phases are not fixed and if the representation has no continuity property). This is one of the starting points to formulate the quantum version of *Noether theorem*.

In summary, if $G$ is such that $g= h^2$ for every $g\in G$ and an associated $h\in G$, then every representation up to phases must be made of *unitary* operators only.

The same argument extends to the more complicated case
 where  $g = h_1^2 \circ \cdots \circ h_N^2$.

Now  consider a *Lie group* $G$.

There is only one *connected component* $G_0$ which is a Lie subgroup as well, the one containing the neutral element $e$. For instance, this component is $SU(2)$ if the full group is $U(2)$, the *orthochronous special Poincaré group* for the *Poincaré group*, $SO(3)$ for $O(3)$, and so on.

In a sufficiently small neighborhood $A$ (which can be fixed to satisfy $A=A^{-1}$) of $e$ in $G_0$, every element $g \in A$ can be written as $g = \exp(t T)$ for some element $T$ of the Lie algebra of $G_0$ and some $t\geq 0$. Therefore $g= h^2$ where $h = \exp((t/2) T)$.

Finally, as for every topological connected group, it is possible to prove that $g \in G_0$ is the product of a finite number (depending on $g$) of elements in every neighborhood $O$ of the neutral element, so that, taking $A=O$,
  $$g = h_1^2 \circ \cdots \circ h_N^2$$

Therefore we can conclude that

**THEOREM.**
*Representing on a Hilbert space of dimension $>1$ a Lie group $G$ in terms of unitary/antiunitary operators up to phases according with Wigner's theorem -- i.e. by means of a unitary projective representation $G\ni g \mapsto U_g$ -- the elements of the connected component of $G$ containing the identity can only be represented by **unitary** operators.*

Antiunitary operators may arise when representing the full Lie group if it has more than a connected component. In particular, the elements connecting different components may be (but also may not) represented by antiunitary operators. A typical example is the time reversal operation in $O(3,1)$ which does not belong to $SO(3,1)_+$.

Perhaps the continuity property mentioned by Weinberg is not referring to the representation but to the elements of the group. The connected component $G_0$ including the neutral element $e$ is exactly made of the elements of $G$ which can be connected to $e$ by means of a **continuous** curve of elements of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have two questions. **(1)** If $U_h$ happens to be antiunitary, then $U_hU_h$ will still be unitary because complex-conjugating twice brings you back to normal. That was your point with writing a group element $g$ as an *even* product of other group elements, right? **(2)** You said that, for any topological connected group, it is possible to express any element as a *finite* product of square-elements. Is there a name for this? Like a theorem?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan **(1)** YES. I now made more mathematically precise my answer, please have a look at this improved version of my answer.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan **(2)** Actually, I mentioned two distinct results. (A) Given a connected topological group and a neighborhood $O$ of the neutral element, then for every $g\in G$, there is a finite set of elements $h_1,\ldots, h_N\in O$ ($N$ depends on $g$) such that $g= h_1\circ\cdots \circ h_N$.   (B) if $G$ is a Lie group, then there is a neighborhood $A$ of the neutral element such that, if $g\in A$, then $g=h^2$ for some $h\in A$.  Finally I used both results for a Lie group taking $O=A$.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Result (B) is a standard fact arising from the properties  of the *exponential map* of Lie groups. Result (A) is a standard result of the theory of topological groups, I do not think that this result has a specific name.

Comment: Here is a proof of (A). Consider the open set $O \ni e$. If $O \neq O^{-1} := \{g^{-1} | g \in O\}$ we can replace $O$ with the open neighborhood of $e$ given by  $O \cap O^{-1}$. So I assume $O=O^{-1}$. Next consider the set $G_0 \subset G$ whose elements are finite products of arbitrarily many elements of $O$.

Comment: $G_0$ is not empty because $e\in G_0$. It is also  open: $gU \subset G_0$ if $g\in G_0$. It is  finally closed: if $g \not \in  G_0$, then $gO$ and $G_0$ are  disjoint since, if  $g f\in G_0$ for $f\in O$, we would have also $g=gff^{-1} \in G_0$. So $G_0$ is the *connected component of $G$ including the neutral element $e$*. Since $G$ is connected, $G=G_0$.

Answer (score 3):

[Wigners theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) says:

> any symmetry transformation of ray space is represented by a linear and unitary or antilinear and antiunitary transformation of Hilbert space. The representation of a symmetry group on Hilbert space is either an ordinary representation or a projective representation.

It seems likely that the space of symmetries of ray space splits into two connected pieces, one consisting of unitary transformations and the other of anti-unitary transformations. But this is, to be honest, a restatement of what Weinberg says in the extract shown. The actual proof of this probably relies on a close examination of Wigner's theorem.

[Here's Bargman's paper](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/Teaching/CFTclass-Bar64.pdf) proving Wigner's theorem; the original theorem is proven in Wigner's book, *Group theory and its application to the the quantum mechanics of atomic spectra*.